# How to write recurrence of any recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I have seen many examples, but couldn't get the right procedure to write the recurrence of any recursive function. For example: If I see these functions, 
how can I write an accurate recurrence?

```
void print (int n)
{
if (n>0)
{cout<< n<<endl;
print(n-1);}
}
```

and

```
int power (int x, int n)
{
        If (n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * power (x, n-1);
}
```

and

```
Int fib (int n)
{
If (n==0 or n==1)
    return 1;
else
    return fib(n-1) +fib (n-2);
}
```

and

```
int numberofDigits(int n) {
  if ((-10 < n) && (n < 10))
    return 1;
  else
    return 1 + numberofDigits(n/10);
}
```

Those are all recursive functions. We can see, some of the functions like (fibonacci, factorial etc) functions have pre-described recurrences on the internet.

But how to write a recurrence by ourselves?

Comment: It would help if you could ask a more specific question, perhaps including an example of a function which you are having trouble with.

Comment: Like first and second example. How can i write recurrence of them?

Comment: please indent your code !

Answer (score 0):

There are generally to cases to a recursive function:

- The recursive case
- The "base" case

For example in the Fibonacci case the base case was "if n is 1 or 0 then the answer is 1", while the recursive case is defined as the sum of the two previous numbers.

The way to create your own recursive function is to isolate the recursive and base cases, and then implement.  So the canonical recursive function would look like this:

```
type my_recursion(type var)
{
  if (/* base case */)
    return /* base case value */;
  else
    return my_recursion(/* pass something in here */);
}
```